# Change component alignment in react mui, ListItemIcon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

Default direction of ListItemIcon is ltr and it start from left to right.
How can I change the default behaviour ?

Any idea apperciate.

code snipped :

```
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {<CloseIcon style={{ direction: "rtl" }} />}
              </ListItemIcon>
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to render (provide an image/example) but try playing with flex-box features like align-items, align-self, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<ListItem>
   <ListItemText primary="Hello" />
   <IconButton edge="end">
      <CloseIcon />
   </IconButton>
</ListItem>
```

Comment: It work with ListItemText , anyway to work without it?

Comment: can you please tell something more about your question? What you are trying to render? or add a sample picture to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how you want to align you items in the `ListItemIcon` like this:

```
<ListItem disablePadding>
    <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon sx={{justifyContent: 'right'}}>
            {<CloseIcon />}
        </ListItemIcon>
    </ListItemButton>
</ListItem>
```